# Deploy non web Java application in AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

First of all I am new to AWS and I want to deploy a simple Java application like below in AWS, I have searched for documentation but couldn't get anything, all documentations refers to deploying WAR or JAR containing embedded servers.

```
public class App {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FTPWatcher ftp = new FTPWatcher(...);
        ftp.start();
    }
}
```

Refered below documentation, it is saying Java SE but it is pointing to deploying webapplication. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[Using the AWS for Java SE platform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-platform.html)

Comment: And exactly what do you have a problem with? Apparently you've created a small application with embedded server? (let's assume you can package it as a self-containing jar)

Comment: No I am not using embedded server, it is a plain standalone Java application, not a web-app

Comment: It doesn't matter, your app doesn't need to be any web app. The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-platform.html) claims `If you only have one JAR file, Elastic Beanstalk will run it with java -jar application_name.jar.`. It means you'll need to package your app as a jar file. So where exactly is the problem? (you may still run your app directly on EC2 without beanstalk)

Comment: I am confused because in same documentation, this is stated "The AWS Elastic Beanstalk Java SE platform is a set of environment configurations for Java **web** applications" also stated about configuring static files "you can configure the proxy server to serve static files (for example, HTML or images) ", anyway I am started setting up. @gusto2 have you deployed standalone Java app in AWS?

Comment: Not really, I used AWS (EC2) before the elastic beanstalk service even existed, so I usually configure all things myself and I am used to it. Indeed, the elasticbeanstalk is intended primarily for web apps (and later for queue workers), so the documentation keeps stating that. If you cannot force to run your app through the beanstalk, you could use directly EC2 service and create your own image or deploy script (for start I assume you will install and start your app manually)

Comment: I think EC2 would be best option, because I am having more number of jars and configuration files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a EC2 instance and setup Java on that.

Below are the links I refereed,

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/gs-step-one-create-ec2-resources.html](http://Link%201)
[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/get-set-up-for-amazon-ec2.html](http://Link%202)